# Trying to update the DOM with dropdown select

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the content displayed to be manipulated by selecting a dropdown option. Here's what I have so far. It doesn't work.

HTML - here's an example of my dropdown.

```
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="Week1" id="Week1drop">Week 1 - Greetings, Common Adjectives & Planets</option>
</select>
```

The div below will be hidden by default using {display: none} in CSS.

```
<div id="week1">
  <h1>Greetings, Common Adjectives & Planets</h1>
</div>
```

JavaScript - Below I've got an event listener to check for a change to the dropdown, which whill call the UpdateDom Function.

The function should be identifying that the user has selected Week1 on the dropdown and using Jquery .show() to make the Div visible.

```
document.getElementById("dropdown").addEventListener("change", updateDom);

function updateDOM () {
  if (document.getElementById('dropdown').value == "Week1") {
    $("#week1").show();
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense, does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Sorry guys, I've just realized it was because my event listener was calling updateDom instead of updateDOM. Noob alert.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the typo you found yourself, if you have jQuery, USE it.
Also options do not have IDs

```js
$("#dropdown").on("change", function() {
  $("#week1").toggle(this.value == "Week1"); // same as $(this).val()
}).change(); // initialise on load
```

```css
#week1 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="Week1">Week 1 - Greetings, Common Adjectives & Planets</option>
</select>

<div id="week1">
  <h1>Greetings, Common Adjectives & Planets</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the tips. Your changes made the actual code for my page a lot cleaner. I was having to use .show() and .hide() for all options to make it work, it looked messy. If you wouldn't mind, could you explain how your code works? I'm not sure what this.value does?

Comment: `this.value` is same as the jQuery `$(this).val()` - it is the value of the element in the selector in this case `$("#dropdown")` - it is just quicker to type